# Is it possible to return multiple member levels in multiple Excel columns using Hyperion Smart View?

Tags: excel, hyperion

Is it possible to return multiple member levels in multiple Excel columns?  This would make it suitable for using as a pivot table data source.

For example:

Smart View returns data like this:

```
  Dec
  Nov
  Oct
Q4
  Sep
  Aug
  Jul
Q3
```

I would like to return data like this:

```
Q4 Dec
Q4 Nov
Q4 Oct
Q3 Sep
Q3 Aug
Q3 Jul
```

Because Q4 and Dec (for example) are levels from the same dimension, Smart View will not let you have them in multiple columns ("Member out of place").

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that through Smart View.

A unpleasant solution would be creating an assisting dimension that reflects the Q1-Q4 relationship with the regular Period's level-0 members (Jan-Dec). It is not recommended since it will increase the number of blocks.

```
Period     Dummy Dim     <Data>
Jan        Q1             10
Feb        Q1             20
Mar        Q1             30
Apr        Q2             40
May        Q2             50
.          .              .
.          .              .
.          .              .
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, a better solution is, you can create a dynamic calc member (say `A001`) on a dense dimension, and write the formula as

```
IF(@ISMBR(Jan))
    A101->No_Location;
ELSEIF(@ISMBR(Feb))
    A102->No_Location;
.
.
.
ELSEIF(@ISMBR(Dec))
    A112->No_Location;
ENDIF
```

Where `A101~A112` are supporting members where you store the text `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4` in a dedicated/static place (like `No_Location`). Then you put the dynamic calc member `A001` onto any forms or ad hoc sheets.